# Как записать значение из AJAX запроса в переменную PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Пробовал множеством способов.
Сам запрос

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "test.php",
                    data: godata,
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    success: function(res) {
                        pid = res["PaymentId"];
                        
                    }
                    });
```

```
document.write("<?php $qwe = ?>" + res['PaymentURL']);
```

```
$qwe = print "<script>document.write(pid);</script>";
```

С вариантом echo не получится, т.к данные из этой переменной уходят в mysql запрос

Comment: а где тут ajax запрос?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего

```
success: function(res) {
    pid = res.PaymentId;
}
```

Comment: Это просто запись в переменную JS, а мне эту записанную переменную нужно в PHP записать

Comment: Переменные PHP - это сервер сайд, jQuery - клиентская сторона. Не совсем понимаю что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: @АлександрВайнберг какую переменную...pid ? Ну так отправьте её обратно серверу, только вот зачем, если в нее записался ответ сервера..

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript-это язык работающий на стороне клиента, а PHP-на стороне сервера.
Для того чтобы передать переменную из JS в PHP необходимо придумывать костыли.

Как вариант который встречался на проде, записывать данные из JS в cookie в зашифрованном виде а потом уже извлекать в PHP.

Другой вариант передавать значение из JS в отдельный обработчик PHP при помощи POST или GET.